# Translating Python Code from gurobipy to PuLP in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, traveling-salesman, gurobi, pulp

I'm new to PuLP and LP in general. While [translating the code](https://github.com/natebrix/capitoltour/blob/master/tour.py) meant for `gurobipi` library so it can be used with `PuLP`, I am stuck at the following gurobipy code which creates the variables.

```
# Create variables.
# x[i, j] is 1 if the edge i->j is on the optimal tour, and 0 otherwise.
x = {}
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        x[i,j] = m.addVar(obj=dist[i][j], vtype=GRB.BINARY,
                             name='x'+str(i)+'_'+str(j))
        x[j,i] = x[i,j]
```

`m.addVar` allows the objective coefficient to be defined usig the `obj` parameter. How can the same be done in `PuLP`? It's [docs for `pulp.LpVariable`](http://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/pulp.html#pulp.LpVariable) does not seem to have a similar parameter...

Also, are there any example code for solving the TSP in Python using PuLP? That will help a lot as a reference!

---

Here's my code so far, without looking at subtours. The results of the decision variables `x_ij` seems to be very wrong, being equal to `1.0` only when `i == j`. Is my attempt correct so far?

**Result**

```
0_0: 1.0
0_5: 1.0
1_1: 1.0
1_15: 1.0
2_2: 1.0
2_39: 1.0
3_3: 1.0
3_26: 1.0
4_4: 1.0
4_42: 1.0
5_5: 1.0
5_33: 1.0
6_6: 1.0
6_31: 1.0
7_7: 1.0
7_38: 1.0
8_8: 1.0
8_24: 1.0
9_9: 1.0
9_26: 1.0
10_4: 1.0
10_10: 1.0
11_11: 1.0
11_12: 1.0
12_11: 1.0
12_12: 1.0
13_13: 1.0
13_17: 1.0
14_14: 1.0
14_18: 1.0
15_1: 1.0
15_15: 1.0
16_3: 1.0
16_16: 1.0
17_13: 1.0
17_17: 1.0
18_14: 1.0
18_18: 1.0
19_19: 1.0
19_20: 1.0
20_4: 1.0
20_20: 1.0
21_21: 1.0
21_25: 1.0
22_22: 1.0
22_27: 1.0
23_21: 1.0
23_23: 1.0
24_8: 1.0
24_24: 1.0
25_21: 1.0
25_25: 1.0
26_26: 1.0
26_43: 1.0
27_27: 1.0
27_38: 1.0
28_28: 1.0
28_47: 1.0
29_29: 1.0
29_31: 1.0
30_30: 1.0
30_34: 1.0
31_29: 1.0
31_31: 1.0
32_25: 1.0
32_32: 1.0
33_28: 1.0
33_33: 1.0
34_30: 1.0
34_34: 1.0
35_35: 1.0
35_42: 1.0
36_36: 1.0
36_47: 1.0
37_36: 1.0
37_37: 1.0
38_27: 1.0
38_38: 1.0
39_39: 1.0
39_44: 1.0
40_40: 1.0
40_43: 1.0
41_41: 1.0
41_45: 1.0
42_4: 1.0
42_42: 1.0
43_26: 1.0
43_43: 1.0
44_39: 1.0
44_44: 1.0
45_15: 1.0
45_45: 1.0
46_40: 1.0
46_46: 1.0
47_28: 1.0
47_47: 1.0



...
```

**PuLP Code**

```
def get_dist(tsp):
    with open(tsp, 'rb') as tspfile:
        r = csv.reader(tspfile, delimiter='\t')
        d = [row for row in r]

    d = d[1:] # skip header row
    locs = set([r[0] for r in d]) | set([r[1] for r in d])
    loc_map = {l:i for i, l in enumerate(locs)}
    idx_map = {i:l for i, l in enumerate(locs)}
    dist = [(loc_map[r[0]], loc_map[r[1]], r[2]) for r in d]
    return dist, idx_map


def dist_from_coords(dist, n):
    points = []
    for i in range(n):
        points.append([0] * n)
    for i, j, v in dist:
        points[i][j] = points[j][i] = float(v)
    return points


def find_tour():
    tsp_file = `/Users/test/` + 'my-waypoints-dist-dur.tsv'
    coords, idx_map = get_dist(tsp_file)
    n = len(idx_map)
    dist = dist_from_coords(coords, n)


    # Define the problem
    m = pulp.LpProblem('TSP', pulp.LpMinimize)


    # Create variables
    # x[i,j] is 1 if edge i->j is on the optimal tour, and 0 otherwise
    # Also forbid loops
    x = {}
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            lowerBound = 0
            upperBound = 1

            # Forbid loops
            if i == j:
                upperBound = 0
                print i,i

            x[i,j] = pulp.LpVariable('x' + str(i) + '_' + str(j), lowerBound, upperBound, pulp.LpBinary)
            x[j,i] = x[i,j]


    # Define the objective function to minimize
    m += pulp.lpSum([dist[i][j] * x[i,j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n)])


    # Add degree-2 constraint
    for i in range(n):
        m += pulp.lpSum([x[i,j] for j in range(n)]) == 2


    status = m.solve()
    print pulp.LpStatus[status]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if pulp.value(x[i,j]) >0:
                print str(i) + '_' + str(j) + ': ' + str( pulp.value(x[i,j]) )

find_tour()
```

**my-waypoints-dist-dur.tsv** [(Full version)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43ba3f6337556eae4ce8104b8ed5992b)

```
waypoint1   waypoint2   distance_m  duration_s
Michigan State Capitol, Lansing, MI 48933   Rhode Island State House, 82 Smith Street, Providence, RI 02903 1242190 41580
Minnesota State Capitol, St Paul, MN 55155  New Mexico State Capitol, Santa Fe, NM 87501    1931932 64455
```

Comment: Skip the objective as beeing part of the variable and just formulate a classic optimization function (i use gurobi a lot and never used this)! Also why do you need this? A TSP-solver written like that will be slow as hell compared to highly complex optimized approaches. (I once coded a simple TSP-formulation for [cvxpy](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/master/examples/tsp_mip.py) for testing my cbc-interface). It follows the formulation of wikipedia and is much more compact compared to your link.

Comment: @sascha As per your suggestion, I am following the formulation based off Wikipedia. Updated the question with new code. I cant figure out whats wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: why didn't you start from a 4-node case with only distance? to test the water .

Comment: You seem to have figured out the "objective" question. As you've deduced, that's done in PuLP using the problem += LpSum(dist[i][j] * x[i][j]). You may want to update your question saying that you already figured that part out?

Answer (score 0):

While creating the variables:

- Changed the name of the variable to be slightly more pythonic in formatting
- `x[j,i] = x[i,j]` is incorrect. This is the Python concept of references. All objects in Python have a reference and when you assign one variable to two names x[i,j] and x[j,i], this results in both of them pointing to the same object. If you modify x[i,j] in your formulation, x[j,i] will also change.

In terms of the Traveling Salesperson Problem, that means if you go from A-->B (ie x[A][B] == 1, then you also travel from B-->A. Which is why you're getting endless `1.0` values in your path variables.

Corrected variable definition then becomes:

```
x[i,j] = pulp.LpVariable('x_%s_%s'%(i,j), lowerBound, upperBound, pulp.LpBinary)
x[j,i] = pulp.LpVariable('x_%s_%s'%(j,i), lowerBound, upperBound, pulp.LpBinary)
```